# Таймер для Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

В App Engine Whitelist указан класс java.util.Timer, но, как вы знаете, App Engine не позволяет запускать новые потоки. Поэтому толку от java.util.Timer в Whitelist не слишком много.

Можно ли каким-то образом организовать на Google App Engine примитивный таймер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока что успешно работает такой примитивный вариант реализации таймера: при первом нажатии на кнопку  старта таймера (если в сессии данный параметр не установлен, считается что нажатие - первое) в сессию записывается текущее время:

```
session.setAttribute("startTime", System.currentTimeMillis())
```

Затем на клиенте организовывается AJAX-опрос. Через определенные промежутки времени клиент отсылает запрос на сервер. На сервере время определяется по элементарной формуле:

```
time = System.currentTimeMillis() - session.getAttribute("startTime")
```

Таким образом получается добиться нормальной точности. И лично мне такое решение кажется более приемлемым, чем таймер на стороне клиента, значение которого отправляется на сервер в виде параметра при очередном опросе.